# Checking if a user is verified in db

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to check if a user is verified, if he is then it will display the verified icon. However I keep getting errors while trying to echo out the image. I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()

Any help ?

```
mysql_query ("SELECT verified FROM users_steam WHERE steamid='$player->steamid'");
                    if ('verified' > 0) {
                        echo "<img src='img/verified.png'>";    
                    }
```

Don't mind the $player->steamid, it's from steam openid api.

Comment: the deprecated MySQL extension was removed from php 7

Comment: given that this question relates to veriying the user, it should not be using mysql - update to PDO and use prepared statements :for_security

Comment: @gavgrif any chance you could show me how to write this in PDO ?

Comment: @Andreas Eilertsen Lybo - better you do some research on PDO and try to put something together and then post your query if you can't get it to work. SO is not a code providing service, but a forum of assistance once you have tried to do stuff.

Comment: @Keyser_Soze - you should probably do some research on PDO as well - the alternative that you posted and then deleted was NOT PDO. just sayin!

Comment: @gavgrif Looked a bit into it now but I can't get it to work. Tried this:
$pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;steam_db","root","");
   $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->query("SELECT * FROM users_steam WHERE steamid='$player->steamid'");
   while($row = $pdoResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if($row['verified']==1) {
     echo 'You did it!'; 
    }
   }

Comment: If you're getting this error it also means you're not doing the required `mysql_connect()` to connect to the database. In other words, it looks like you're randomly copy/pasting stuff from the internet and fiddling with it until it works. This is not a very good way to write programs...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker No, but thanks for the input. I was watching a tutorial, but it doesn't work the same way for me as it does for them ;)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query does not work in the new versions of PHP. You can use mysqli:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

or PDO. 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php